# Ruby Selenium WebDriver - get return value of execute_script

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

Simple question here - when I use `execute_script` in a Ruby Selenium test, is there a way I can get the result of the JavaScript I ran?

This is the code I'm executing: `driver.execute_script '$.active'`

Edit: The solution is so simple. I forgot to include `return` in the script.

Comment: I think I just figured it out - I was missing the "return" statement from the script. It should be `driver.execute_script 'return $.active'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add the `return`:

```
driver.execute_script 'return $.active'
```

Comment: Yep, just figured that out as you posted. I feel so silly. Thank you!